# Crystal sqlite3 create new database

Tags: database, sqlite, crystal-lang

How do a create a new sqlite database using Crystal?

When trying:

```
DB.open "sqlite3://.data.db" do |db|
end
```

I get no errors.
But when I attempt to do it in the home directory:

```
DB.open "sqlite3://~/.data.db" do |db|
end
```

I get a `DB::ConnectionRefused` exception.

How do I get to open a database in the home directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
DB.open "sqlite3://.data.db" do |db|
end
```

you create `data.db` in the current directory. Try running [usage example](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal-sqlite3#usage) and you will get some output.

To create/open db in a home directory, you need simply to expand the path (`~` not working in sqlite URI):

```
db_path = File.expand_path "~/data.db"
DB.open "sqlite3://#{db_path}" do |db|
end
```